How do I build MAUI (iOS) app using Release configuration but with Development Provisional profile?
My MAUI app is working fine locally but when uploading to and testing with TestFlight, the app crashes with no useful information at all and I have no idea what could be the case.
I am trying to get a Release build but then I cannot even install it locally on my iPhone because it uses an App-store provisional profile. If I try to force it to sign with a development provisional profile (<CodesignProvision>MAUI Test App(Dev distro)</CodesignProvision>), the build fails with this error:

No iOS signing identities match the specified provisioning profile 'MAUI Test App(Dev distro)'

The same build command would work if I build with Debug configuration instead. Please advise on how I should proceed.

Also here's the crash log I got from TestFlight and I could not get any useful information from it. The app crashes immediately after start, not even the splash screen shows up.
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0


Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000020c17c558 __pthread_kill + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022cdfa118 pthread_kill + 268 (pthread.c:1670)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001d4992178 abort + 180 (abort.c:118)
3   QrCodeGenerator                 0x000000010509a49c 0x102dec000 + 36365468
4   QrCodeGenerator                 0x000000010501eda0 0x102dec000 + 35859872
5   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x000000022cd5e274 _sigtramp + 56 (sigtramp.c:116)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022cdfa118 pthread_kill + 268 (pthread.c:1670)
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001d4992178 abort + 180 (abort.c:118)
8   QrCodeGenerator                 0x0000000104ee6d98 0x102dec000 + 34581912
9   QrCodeGenerator                 0x0000000104edc92c 0x102dec000 + 34539820
10  QrCodeGenerator                 0x0000000104edca74 0x102dec000 + 34540148
11  QrCodeGenerator                 0x0000000104ff7fbc 0x102dec000 + 35700668
12  QrCodeGenerator                 0x0000000104f3ca64 0x102dec000 + 34933348
13  QrCodeGenerator                 0x0000000104f3c584 0x102dec000 + 34932100
14  QrCodeGenerator                 0x0000000104f3e20c 0x102dec000 + 34939404
15  QrCodeGenerator                 0x0000000104db9010 0x102dec000 + 33345552
16  QrCodeGenerator                 0x0000000104f3e434 0x102dec000 + 34939956
17  QrCodeGenerator                 0x0000000104f3bce0 0x102dec000 + 34929888
18  QrCodeGenerator                 0x0000000105001ee8 0x102dec000 + 35741416
19  QrCodeGenerator                 0x0000000104ff7f54 0x102dec000 + 35700564
20  QrCodeGenerator                 0x0000000104f3ca64 0x102dec000 + 34933348
21  QrCodeGenerator                 0x0000000104f3c584 0x102dec000 + 34932100
22  QrCodeGenerator                 0x0000000104f3e20c 0x102dec000 + 34939404
23  QrCodeGenerator                 0x0000000104db9010 0x102dec000 + 33345552
24  QrCodeGenerator                 0x0000000104f3e434 0x102dec000 + 34939956
25  QrCodeGenerator                 0x0000000104f3bce0 0x102dec000 + 34929888
26  QrCodeGenerator                 0x0000000105001ee8 0x102dec000 + 35741416
27  QrCodeGenerator                 0x0000000104ff7f54 0x102dec000 + 35700564
28  QrCodeGenerator                 0x0000000104f3ca64 0x102dec000 + 34933348
29  QrCodeGenerator                 0x0000000104f3c584 0x102dec000 + 34932100
30  QrCodeGenerator                 0x0000000104f3e20c 0x102dec000 + 34939404
31  QrCodeGenerator                 0x0000000104db9010 0x102dec000 + 33345552
32  QrCodeGenerator                 0x0000000104f3e434 0x102dec000 + 34939956
33  QrCodeGenerator                 0x0000000104f3bce0 0x102dec000 + 34929888
34  QrCodeGenerator                 0x0000000105001ee8 0x102dec000 + 35741416
35  QrCodeGenerator                 0x0000000104ff7f54 0x102dec000 + 35700564
36  QrCodeGenerator                 0x0000000104f3ca64 0x102dec000 + 34933348
37  QrCodeGenerator                 0x0000000104f3c584 0x102dec000 + 34932100
38  QrCodeGenerator                 0x0000000104f3e20c 0x102dec000 + 34939404
39  QrCodeGenerator                 0x0000000104db9010 0x102dec000 + 33345552
40  QrCodeGenerator                 0x0000000104f3e434 0x102dec000 + 34939956
41  QrCodeGenerator                 0x0000000104f3bce0 0x102dec000 + 34929888
42  QrCodeGenerator                 0x0000000105001ee8 0x102dec000 + 35741416
43  QrCodeGenerator                 0x0000000104ff7f54 0x102dec000 + 35700564
44  QrCodeGenerator                 0x0000000104ffca9c 0x102dec000 + 35719836
45  QrCodeGenerator                 0x0000000104feb974 0x102dec000 + 35649908
46  QrCodeGenerator                 0x0000000104fefe00 0x102dec000 + 35667456
47  QrCodeGenerator                 0x0000000104f9be64 0x102dec000 + 35323492
48  QrCodeGenerator                 0x0000000104f594d0 0x102dec000 + 35050704
49  QrCodeGenerator                 0x0000000104f59254 0x102dec000 + 35050068
50  QrCodeGenerator                 0x0000000104f3866c 0x102dec000 + 34915948
51  QrCodeGenerator                 0x0000000104fef6a0 0x102dec000 + 35665568
52  QrCodeGenerator                 0x0000000104ff56f0 0x102dec000 + 35690224
53  QrCodeGenerator                 0x0000000104db8518 0x102dec000 + 33342744
54  QrCodeGenerator                 0x0000000104db9424 0x102dec000 + 33346596
55  QrCodeGenerator                 0x000000010505dd30 0x102dec000 + 36117808
56  dyld                            0x00000001ec970dec start + 2220 (dyldMain.cpp:1165)

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022cdf3b74 start_wqthread + 0 (:-1)

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022cdf3b74 start_wqthread + 0 (:-1)

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022cdf3b74 start_wqthread + 0 (:-1)

Thread 4 name:
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000020c176558 __psynch_cvwait + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022cdfb078 _pthread_cond_wait + 1232 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   QrCodeGenerator                 0x0000000104f35940 0x102dec000 + 34904384
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022cdf46b8 _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:893)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022cdf3b88 thread_start + 8 (:-1)


Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0xffffffff981071a0   x5: 0x0000000000000008   x6: 0x000000016d00e2e0   x7: 0x000000016d00d9d0
    x8: 0xe5838081ed9aeb7f   x9: 0xe5838083ce5aea3f  x10: 0x0000000000000200  x11: 0x000000016d00da40
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000103312c98  x14: 0x0000000013e40000  x15: 0x00000000000000ff
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000223c00140  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x0000000000000103  x21: 0x0000000223c00220  x22: 0x0000000000000010  x23: 0x0000000000001f18
   x24: 0x00000001056667d4  x25: 0x0000000000000028  x26: 0x00000000000001b8  x27: 0x000000010552a1b0
   x28: 0x0000000281eb92e0   fp: 0x000000016d00e2f0   lr: 0x000000022cdfa118
    sp: 0x000000016d00e2d0   pc: 0x000000020c17c558 cpsr: 0x40001000
   esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault


Binary Images:
        0x102dec000 -         0x1052fbfff QrCodeGenerator arm64  <29664011a0893b469ae20a3130723e9b> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/121A1B7F-2D24-45BE-BECF-91FE27D523F4/QrCodeGenerator.app/QrCodeGenerator
        0x1058b8000 -         0x1058bffff RecaptchaInterop arm64  <fee2cf0b25b53d758c16cad6a9c317d0> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/121A1B7F-2D24-45BE-BECF-91FE27D523F4/QrCodeGenerator.app/Frameworks/RecaptchaInterop.framework/RecaptchaInterop
        0x1058cc000 -         0x1058dffff FirebaseCore arm64  <65586175a2e638e6877bd61dab810818> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/121A1B7F-2D24-45BE-BECF-91FE27D523F4/QrCodeGenerator.app/Frameworks/FirebaseCore.framework/FirebaseCore
        0x105900000 -         0x10590ffff FBLPromises arm64  <cb9ac3cbaf36341f860ba5ab6eabb1eb> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/121A1B7F-2D24-45BE-BECF-91FE27D523F4/QrCodeGenerator.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises
        0x10592c000 -         0x105933fff nanopb arm64  <a873401295d7337fb577a3dd1fb8c538> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/121A1B7F-2D24-45BE-BECF-91FE27D523F4/QrCodeGenerator.app/Frameworks/nanopb.framework/nanopb
        0x1059cc000 -         0x105a23fff FirebaseAuth arm64  <e52f360d6d1d36168e49d920bdc8123f> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/121A1B7F-2D24-45BE-BECF-91FE27D523F4/QrCodeGenerator.app/Frameworks/FirebaseAuth.framework/FirebaseAuth
        0x105acc000 -         0x105af7fff GTMSessionFetcher arm64  <91b96b0e68f53e939a765b1f35241c80> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/121A1B7F-2D24-45BE-BECF-91FE27D523F4/QrCodeGenerator.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher
        0x105b3c000 -         0x105b63fff GoogleDataTransport arm64  <079782d237533b7cbd89b3249fc6be5c> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/121A1B7F-2D24-45BE-BECF-91FE27D523F4/QrCodeGenerator.app/Frameworks/GoogleDataTransport.framework/GoogleDataTransport
        0x105ba0000 -         0x105bbffff GoogleUtilities arm64  <9d1961d505f735faa3dfce94000d0808> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/121A1B7F-2D24-45BE-BECF-91FE27D523F4/QrCodeGenerator.app/Frameworks/GoogleUtilities.framework/GoogleUtilities
        0x105bec000 -         0x105c1ffff leveldb arm64  <e62088b0628b3275a555806120fc71f3> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/121A1B7F-2D24-45BE-BECF-91FE27D523F4/QrCodeGenerator.app/Frameworks/leveldb.framework/leveldb
        0x105c64000 -         0x105c6bfff FirebaseAppCheckInterop arm64  <04674bc3b05632a38843804a1fd45dcd> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/121A1B7F-2D24-45BE-BECF-91FE27D523F4/QrCodeGenerator.app/Frameworks/FirebaseAppCheckInterop.framework/FirebaseAppCheckInterop
        0x105c78000 -         0x105c7ffff FirebaseAuthInterop arm64  <62a5dc98f2623b8381365e6f7d8693df> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/121A1B7F-2D24-45BE-BECF-91FE27D523F4/QrCodeGenerator.app/Frameworks/FirebaseAuthInterop.framework/FirebaseAuthInterop
        0x105c8c000 -         0x105c93fff FirebaseCoreExtension arm64  <b7ce75235c8e308b9cc135d2296b94fd> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/121A1B7F-2D24-45BE-BECF-91FE27D523F4/QrCodeGenerator.app/Frameworks/FirebaseCoreExtension.framework/FirebaseCoreExtension
        0x105ca0000 -         0x105cbbfff FirebaseCoreInternal arm64  <4c2776bdd825359d9b38f1c9baa49763> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/121A1B7F-2D24-45BE-BECF-91FE27D523F4/QrCodeGenerator.app/Frameworks/FirebaseCoreInternal.framework/FirebaseCoreInternal
        0x105cfc000 -         0x105d03fff FirebaseMessagingInterop arm64  <4056ef4240743b58abbb50c84ee1530f> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/121A1B7F-2D24-45BE-BECF-91FE27D523F4/QrCodeGenerator.app/Frameworks/FirebaseMessagingInterop.framework/FirebaseMessagingInterop
        0x105d10000 -         0x105d1bfff FirebaseRemoteConfigInterop arm64  <ab017fd9ff873df6ab3b3c50eb966ee1> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/121A1B7F-2D24-45BE-BECF-91FE27D523F4/QrCodeGenerator.app/Frameworks/FirebaseRemoteConfigInterop.framework/FirebaseRemoteConfigInterop
        0x105d34000 -         0x105d63fff FirebaseSharedSwift arm64  <a5d004cdde6a355b9517de75389b8b8f> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/121A1B7F-2D24-45BE-BECF-91FE27D523F4/QrCodeGenerator.app/Frameworks/FirebaseSharedSwift.framework/FirebaseSharedSwift
        0x105db8000 -         0x105dcbfff Promises arm64  <4cc9c433ee8b34549814a6ef2392426a> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/121A1B7F-2D24-45BE-BECF-91FE27D523F4/QrCodeGenerator.app/Frameworks/Promises.framework/Promises
        0x105dec000 -         0x105e0bfff FirebaseSessions arm64  <81d40dbc0f7d326cbc2ebc33d7a63950> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/121A1B7F-2D24-45BE-BECF-91FE27D523F4/QrCodeGenerator.app/Frameworks/FirebaseSessions.framework/FirebaseSessions
        0x105e4c000 -         0x105e9bfff FirebaseCrashlytics arm64  <5ad92dd052c2326ba7cc24935730506a> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/121A1B7F-2D24-45BE-BECF-91FE27D523F4/QrCodeGenerator.app/Frameworks/FirebaseCrashlytics.framework/FirebaseCrashlytics
        0x105f20000 -         0x105f37fff FirebaseInstallations arm64  <e94d5c49d82c32829e1dfeef5fdbe7fa> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/121A1B7F-2D24-45BE-BECF-91FE27D523F4/QrCodeGenerator.app/Frameworks/FirebaseInstallations.framework/FirebaseInstallations
        0x105fe8000 -         0x105ff3fff libobjc-trampolines.dylib arm64e  <e57f2d6df3f138fea6c21fb6f6731d4c> /private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/libobjc-trampolines.dylib
        0x1d4975000 -         0x1d49f2ff3 libsystem_c.dylib arm64e  <72233fdeddfe3e78b9912dece8cd78c5> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
        0x1ec95b000 -         0x1ec9e0923 dyld arm64e  <41605dc7f41237d1b51bfee1a26701e9> /usr/lib/dyld
        0x20c175000 -         0x20c1acff7 libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64e  <5998c9aec77e3681bd6c0883c89297cf> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
        0x22cd5c000 -         0x22cd62fef libsystem_platform.dylib arm64e  <2e6c66fc2eb934f9995bae0b16e030c4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
        0x22cdf3000 -         0x22cdfeff3 libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64e  <b1ee57e144843714ba1a104330ca10c6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib

EOF



try modifying your Debug config to use the same linker settings as the release config.  That is the major difference between the two configs

@Jason is there anything I should be aware of? I have checked my project properties, the only thing different properties between the Debug and Release builds are CodesignProvision and CodesignKey. I do not modify any linker settings. If I missed it somehow, how do I do that please?

@Jason I found the documentation and added <MtouchLink>SdkOnly</MtouchLink> for Debug build. Unfortunately the app still runs normally. I have also added <MtouchLink>None</MtouchLink> and publish it again to TestFlight. I will test it in a few minutes to see if it helps.

With <MtouchLink>None</MtouchLink> added, the app no longer crashes but it's troublesome. The build took about 15mins to finish and I have to add tons of unused permissions like NSAppleMusicUsageDescription or NSCalendarsUsageDescription but my app doesn't use any of those.

that's not a solution, its narrowing down the problem.  Now you know the linker is stripping something out that you need.  You just need to figure out what it is

@Jason thank you very much, at least there's some direction. I will try finding what I need to preserve. Is there any tip?

Very strange, I used <MtouchLink>SdkOnly</MtouchLink> instead and the build is good (27MB vs 73MB None) and there is no crash. Problem is, I thought SdkOnly is the default setting... Anyway, I am happy my app is not crashing anymore.

Well, as an answer:

how to build MAUI (iOS) app using Release configuration but with Development Provisional profile

Using <MtouchLink>SdkOnly</MtouchLink> can avoid crashing. For more information, you can refer to the official doc: Linking a .NET MAUI iOS app.

Isn't this the default setting for Release build?

Yes, it is. You can report it on Developer Community/Visual Studio.
